# Error al crear el directorio y crear el fichero

Tags: java

Tengo una consulta a un xml y la idea es que tengo que meterla en un archivo pero no me crea el directorio correctamente. El problema es que no me deja escribir en C:
Este es mi metodo

```
public void CrearFichero1() {
    String resultado = operaciones(1);
    String[] lines = resultado.split("\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
        String datos = lines[i];
        if ((i + 1) % 9 == 0) {
            try {
                String ruta ="c:\\ADtarea52020";
                File archivo = new File(ruta);
                archivo.mkdirs();
                File archivo2 = new File("c:\\ADtarea52020\\libro" + (i + 1) / 9 + ".xml");
                BufferedWriter bw;
                bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(archivo2));
                bw.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Error al escribir");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Falla en el bufferwrite

Comment: Has probado a cambiar el sentido de las barras de la dirección ? por ejemplo en vez de c:\\  que sea c:// ?

Comment: porque iba poner las barra como si fuera una url?